# Different behaviour between formatting strings for TimeSpan and DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

While coding today, I noticed something odd with timespans and formatting strings. I was trying to print a timespan, for instance `01:03:37` as `1:03:37` (without the leading 0 for hours). So I used the format string `h:mm:ss`. This, however, gave me a leading 0. If I converted the TimeSpan to a DateTime and did the same thing again, the `h` formatting string worked as I expected.

A sample console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var time = new TimeSpan(01, 03, 37);

        var culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:h:mm:ss}", time));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:hh:mm:ss}", time));

        Console.WriteLine((new DateTime(time.Ticks)).ToString("h:mm:ss", culture));
        Console.WriteLine((new DateTime(time.Ticks)).ToString("hh:mm:ss", culture));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
01:03:37
01:03:37  // <-- expected: 1:03:37
01:03:37
1:03:37
01:03:37
```

Why is the TimeSpan and DateTime behaving differently?

Comment: A tip, you can use `Console.WriteLine("{0:h:mm:ss}", time,)` instead because you already set the current culture, it is not needed to use `string.Format` with the culture-parameter.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your formatting string do not work for `TimeSpan` and `TimeSpan.ToString()` always returns ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28VS.71%29.aspx)):

> A string that represents the value of
>   this instance. The return value is of
>   the form:
>
> [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.ff]

Answer (score 6):

Until .Net 4.0, TimeSpans do not support format strings.

In .Net 4.0, the format strings are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx.

Comment: Thanks ... missed the 'h' info in the document (removed from answer).